# Add Background image to sonata admin

Tags: html, css, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I work in symfony project and I use SonataAdminBundle for the Back-End.

I like to Override the template of the sonata to add a **background-image** to the content-section. 
How can I get It ? Someone have idea ? thank you